# Placing an image next to text / link content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a design that I'm trying to match. I need an image, a .gif, next to the text content. But I just plain can't get it to there, and it's driving me mad.

Reduced test case here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QL49W/2/

End goal is a photoshopped design. Not sure how to translate it into code though:

[image]

My HTML is below. In the jsfiddle, I'm using a lot more CSS & JS.

```
<section id="newslettersignup">
    <div class="container White_BG">
        <div class="pull-left newsletter">
            <h2>E-mail Deals</h2>
            Sign up to receive Sales &amp; exclusive news!<br>
            We will not sell or rent your email address. <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/privacy-policy/a/3/" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#F25C27;">Privacy Policy</a>.<br><br>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://www.gliq.com/cgi-bin/subunsub">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="hidden" name="acctname" value="amleo">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" value=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/subscribe-successful/a/47/">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputIcon" class="input-xlarge" name="email">
                    <input value="SUBSCRIBE" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Catalog" class="pull-right catrr">
            <div class="catalog">
                    <h2>Catalogs</h2>
                    <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="catalogrequestpopup.aspx?catalog_id=0001&amp;name=2014 Catalog Request" title="Request a Catalog" style="text-decoration:underline;"><span style="color:#F25C27;">Request a Free Catalog</span></a> or<br>
                    <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/catalogs.aspx" title="Catalogs" style="text-decoration:underline;">
                    <span style="color:#F25C27;">View Online Catalog</span></a>

                    <div class="CatalogGif">
                        <img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/MG14_pro_animatedcover.gif" align="right">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ok! Replaced font with span.

Comment: Float the image, make other content display as `inline(-block)`, position it absolutely within the container … take your pick.

Comment: None of those worked.

Comment: Well then you might have to update you knowledge about layouting with CSS a little …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into the grid-system of Bootstrap, which would (as far as I can see), would solve your problem :)

I made a sample fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/QL49W/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">Hello</div>
        <div class="span3">world</div>
        <div class="span3">This</div>
        <div class="span3">Rocks</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this you a grid with 12 columns, you can break up in way you want 3-3-6, 4-4-4 or just 1-2 and then leave the rest blank.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure how that helps me place the image next to the content at all. http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/